# How to get all the app list including System APPS and user installed APPS?

Tags: java, android

I've used multiple code snippets but nothing is working properly.
For example, By using the below code, I'm getting the APP list but not all like Youtube, Gmail, etc are not showing in my list.

**NB: Working on Emulator but not working on the Real device properly.**

**Code that I've tried:**

```
 1. List<ApplicationInfo> apps = 
      getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

   2. List<PackageInfo> packList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
   
   3.   Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = 
        getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

I need a proper solution that will work on the latest Android version as well as I will get all the app list.

Answer (score 0):

try that,it works with me

```
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    appsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> allApps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : allApps) {
        AppInfo app = new AppInfo();
        app.label = ri.loadLabel(packageManager);
        app.packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;

        Log.i("package ",app.packageName.toString());
        app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
        appsList.add(app);
    }
```

and in the manifest file add this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

and in a manifest file outside the application tag:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. I think you didn't test it. Because you have done the same thing that I did. I've already given my code above, you've just used that. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. shell

```sh
pm list packages
```

code example

```java
private List<String> getPkgList() {
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm list packages");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            line = line.trim();
            if (line.length() > 8) {
                String prefix = line.substring(0, 8);
                if (prefix.equalsIgnoreCase("package:")) {
                    line = line.substring(8).trim();
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(line)) {
                        packages.add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStacktraces();
    }
    return packages;
}
```

2. system api

```java
PackageManager.getInstalledPackages()
```

code example

```java
private List<String> getPkgListNew() {
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        List<PackageInfo> packageInfos = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES |
                PackageManager.GET_SERVICES);
        for (PackageInfo info : packageInfos) {
            String pkg = info.packageName;
            packages.add(pkg);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();;
    }
    return packages;
}


private boolean isSystemApp(PackageInfo pi) {
    boolean isSysApp = (pi.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1;
    boolean isSysUpd = (pi.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP) == 1;
    return isSysApp || isSysUpd;
}
```